# How to "terminate" Get-Content -Wait after another command has finished in batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I'm writing on a batch script for Unity builds with Jenkins.

---

What I did so far

Unity has the problem that by default it it is not very verbous in [`-batchmode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).

So in order to get the output into Jenkins I use [`-logFile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) to make Unity write to a specific logfile.

Until now I'm just able to read this file **after** a build succeeded or failed using

```
Unity.exe -batchmode -logFile JenkinsLOG.txt <more parameters>

type JenkinsLOG.txt
```

---

Now in order to get the content of `JenkinsLOG.txt` in realtime to the Jenkins log view I'm trying to use `start` to run the Unity process in a new console and use [`powershell Get-Content <file> -Wait`](https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-get-tail-like-functionality-on-windows-with-powershell/) to print the content of the logfile in realtime to the console:

```
start Unity.exe -batchmode -logFile JenkinsLOG.txt <more parameters>

powershell Get-Content JenkinsLOG.txt -Wait
```

this works great and I see the output in realtime appearing in Jenkins ...

**But** ... ofcourse the powershell command never terminates so the build process gets stuck still waiting for more lines beeing appended to `JenkinsLOG.txt`.

---

So my question is
**Is there any possibility to tell this powershell command to terminate after the Unity process finished?**

Answer (score 1):

- Get process id you want to monitor
- Spin up a job that tails the log file
- Loop the current console to read output from the job
- Terminate the loop when the process exits
- Clean up jobs

Here it is wrapped up in a function. There is probably a more elegant way, but I couldn't find another way to distinguish between a "timeout" exit of `Wait-Process` and a "process stopped" exit.

```
function TailFile-UntilProcessStops {
    Param ($processID, $filePath)

    $loopBlock = {
        Param($filePath) Get-Content $filePath -Wait -Tail 0
    }
    $TailLoopJob = start-job -scriptBlock $loopBlock -ArgumentList $filePath
    try {
        do {
            $TailLoopJob | Receive-Job
            try {
                Wait-Process -id $processID -ErrorAction Stop -Timeout 1
                $waitMore = $false
            } catch {
                $waitMore = $true
            }
        } while($waitMore)
    } finally {
        Stop-Job $TailLoopJob
        Remove-Job $TailLoopJob
    }
}
```

Here is the test code with Notepad. Make sure the file exists, then modify it. Every time you save, the console should update with more data. Quit Notepad and control returns to the console.

```
$filename = 'h:\asdf\somefile.txt'
$process = start-process -FilePath 'notepad.exe' -ArgumentList @($filename) -PassThru
TailFile-UntilProcessStops -processID $process.id -filepath $filename
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like to try this ... this is now a powershell script not a batch file, right? How would I use this in / call it from a batch script?

Comment: @derHugo, you should use Jenkins PowerShell plugin.

Comment: @Manea I don't really want to .. I have a batch script which is complete. Using Powershell within this batch script was just the only simple way I've found to provide this `tail -f` like behavior without having to install other things. The plug-ins for Jenkins often do not convince me much ..

Comment: You would need to get the PID of your Unity process and pass it to PowerShell; I'm not sure how to do that, but I'm sure the internet will provide with some searching.

Comment: @derHugo, I heavily use poweshell plugin in Jenkins, and it works really well. Plugins are the essence of Jenkins. If you use a lot of scripts, I suggest you to switch from batch to PowerShell, because it is the "new standard" for windows system administration. Some investisment is required to learn, but reward is here: easier than batch, much powerfull, lot of features, tools, scripts availables, etc . I did this step, and when I remember the hell of "for delim "etc, without regrets :)